# Регулярные выражения для дат в Javascript

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Задача
Есть инпут, который принимает текст в формате дате в виде ДД.ММ.ГГГГ
Есть регулрка для проверки соответствия

```
var reg = /^\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{4}$/
var inval = input.value;
```

Чтобы взять день даты, использую регулярку

```
var day = parseInt(inval.match(/^\d{1,2}/));
```

Чтобы взять год, использую регулярку

```
  var year = parseInt(inval.match(/\d{4}$/));
```

Не получается взять месяц. Регулярка ниже не работает

```
var month = parseInt(inval.match(/.+\d{1,2}.+/));
```

Comment: А почему нельзя в регулярное выражение проверки добавить группы и использовать их? Или использовать строковые операции, к примеру String​.prototype​.split()?

Comment: Вопрос, а чем Вам не угодил split()?

Comment: Задачу нужно решить без использования строковых функций

Comment: @Stranger in the Q, использую. Показывает ошибку

Comment: @StrangerintheQ в parse нельзя указать формат даты.

Comment: @XelaNimed, с группами тоже не видит

Comment: Ну как так-то? Сейчас добавлю ответ...

Comment: @XelaNimed д, тут же точки..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Регулярное выражение для проверки даты, которое бы учитывало корректность месяца, даты и года, будет выглядеть сложно.
Поэтому я предлагаю для начала просто проверить на наличие цифр, а затем уже можно проверить значения месяца, даты и года. В любом случае Вы можете просто использовать приведённое регулярное выражение:

```js
var $ = function(id){ return document.getElementById(id); },
minYear = 1900, maxYear = 2100,
// Месяц и дата без ведущих нулей
// regex = new RegExp("^([1-9][0-9]?)\\.([1-9][0-9]?)\\.([1-2][0-9]{3})$"),
// Месяц и дата с ведущими нулями
regex = new RegExp("^([0-9]{2})\\.([0-9]{2})\\.([1-2][0-9]{3})$");

$('run').addEventListener('click', function(){

  let inp = $("input").value;
  if(inp === ""){
    $("output").value = "Input is empty";
    return;
  }
  
  if(regex.test(inp) === false){
    $("output").value = inp + ": RegExp check fail";
    return;
  }
  var reRes = regex.exec(inp),
      year = parseInt(reRes[3], 10),
      month = parseInt(reRes[2], 10) - 1,
      day = parseInt(reRes[1], 10);
  if(day > 31 || month > 12 || year > maxYear || year < minYear) {
    $("output").value = "Date format error";
    return;
  }
  var date = new Date(year, month, day);
  $("output").value = date.toLocaleString();
}, false);
```

```html
<p>Input</p>
<input id="input" value="12.12.2019" />
<p>Output</p>
<textarea id="output" cols="100" rows="4"></textarea>
<p><button id="run">Run</button></p>
```

---

#### Ссылки по теме

- [Регулярные выражения на MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)
- [Онлайн сервис для тестирования RegExp](https://regex101.com/)
- [input type="date"](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/date)
- [поддержка браузерами типа date в input](https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-date)

Comment: Да, довольно сложно. Загвоздка еще именно в том, что нельзя использовать объект RegExp(). Без него задача должна решаться. потому и встрял

Comment: @Павел я не уверен, что правильно Вас понимаю: в комментариях к вопросу Вы сказали, что нельзя использовать строковые функции, теперь говорите, что нельзя использовать RegExp. Поясните в Вашем вопросе, что Вам конкретно нужно и в чём конкретно заключается поставленная перед Вами задача. Можете также пояснить по каким причинам нельзя использовать строковые фунции и RegExp.

Comment: Потому что   это задачки для начинающих. Из функций изучены только Математические операции и Дата и время. И регулярка только азы без объектов. А задача именно такая: Проверить на корректность значение инпута, и вывести сколько человек прожил секунд, минут, часов. Вот и колупаюсь) В теме регулярок не было объектов, только самые азы. Т.е. по факту объект RegExp() не изучен(((

Comment: @Павел тот факт, что Вы не знаете регулярных выражений, не означает что их нельзя использовать. Самое время изучить, т.к. Вы будете сталкиваться с ними постоянно. Регулярное выражение, которое Вы указали в вопросе, тоже объект, просто оно создаётся другим способом.

Comment: Благодарю! ;) Буду изучать глубже.Просто в справочнике, кот. использовал по регуляркам нет примеров с использованием объекта)

Comment: @Павел, Вы, как видится, не выучили и то, что уже прошли. В задаче не сказано, что нужно использовать регулярные выражения. А не сказано потому, что объект `Date`,  проводит собственную проверку. Введите любое значение и попробуйте перевести его в дату

Comment: @Павел обновил ответ добавив в него ссылки на сопутствующие темы и документацию. Так как Вы не отметили ответ как решение, то поясните пожалуйста, что конкретно из предложенного Вас не устраивает либо не подходит для решения Вашей задачи.

Answer (score 0):

Для работы с датами удобно использовать [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/).

Если по-вашему, то каждое число из строки можно взять так:

`var date = "09.05.2019"
[day, month, year] = date.split('.')`

Comment: Строковые функции нельзя использовать

Answer (score 0):

Для решения использовал exec();

```
var inval = input.value;
var regArr = reg.exec(inval);
var day = Number(regArr[1]) // Получаем день;
var month = Number(regArr[2]) // Получаем месяц;
var year = Number(regArr[3]) // Получаем год;
```

Answer (score 0):

Регулярка для формата `d-M-yyyy` с разрешённым необязательным лидирующим нулём у дня и месяца, корректно учитывающая длительность месяцев в том числе в [високосные годы](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4):

```
^((((0?[1-9]-(0?[1-9]|1[0-2]))|([12][0-9]-((0?[13-9])|1[0-2]))|(((1[0-9])|(2[0-8]))-0?2)|(30-((0?[13-9])|1[0-2]))|(31-((0?[13578])|10|12)))-[0-9]{4})|(29-0?2-(([0-9]{2}((0[48])|([2468][048])|([13579][26])))|((([02468][048])|([13579][26]))00))))$
```

Правда написана 6 лет назад, сейчас я бы лучше написал, наверное :)

---

Код для проверки на VB.NET:

```vb
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Module All

Public ReadOnly DateRegex As New Regex("^((((0?[1-9]-(0?[1-9]|1[0-2]))|([12][0-9]-((0?[13-9])|1[0-2]))|(((1[0-9])|(2[0-8]))-0?2)|(30-((0?[13-9])|1[0-2]))|(31-((0?[13578])|10|12)))-[0-9]{4})|(29-0?2-(([0-9]{2}((0[48])|([2468][048])|([13579][26])))|((([02468][048])|([13579][26]))00))))$")

Private Sub Test(Sample As String)
  Console.Write("{0}     ", Sample)

  Dim Temp As Date
  Dim RegexRes As Boolean = DateRegex.IsMatch(Sample)
  Dim ParseRes As Boolean = Date.TryParseExact(Sample, "d-M-yyyy", Nothing, Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, Temp)

  If RegexRes = ParseRes Then
    Console.CursorLeft = 0
  Else
    Console.WriteLine(" - Error: {0} instead of {1}: {2}", RegexRes, ParseRes, Temp.ToString("d-M-yyyy"))
  End If
End Sub

Sub Main()
  Dim Start As Date, Finish As Date

  Start = Now()
  Console.WriteLine(Start.ToString("'started:  'yyyy_MM_dd HH_mm_ss"))

  For Y As Integer = 1 To 9999
    For M As Integer = 0 To 99
      For D As Integer = 0 To 99
        Test(String.Format("{0}-{1}-{2,4:0000}", D, M, Y))
      Next D
      For D As Integer = 0 To 9
        Test(String.Format("{0,2:00}-{1}-{2,4:0000}", D, M, Y))
      Next D
    Next M
    For M As Integer = 0 To 9
      For D As Integer = 0 To 99
        Test(String.Format("{0}-{1,2:00}-{2,4:0000}", D, M, Y))
      Next D
      For D As Integer = 0 To 9
        Test(String.Format("{0,2:00}-{1,2:00}-{2,4:0000}", D, M, Y))
      Next D
    Next M
  Next Y

  Finish = Now()
  Console.WriteLine(Finish.ToString("'finished: 'yyyy_MM_dd HH_mm_ss"))
  Console.WriteLine("time:     {0}", Finish - Start)

  Console.ReadKey()
End Sub

End Module
```

---

PS: Дефис на точку заменить легко, просто не стал, чтоб не накосячить в ответе.